# Product not display on frontend before reindexing in magento2

Tags: magento2, reindex

Product not display after imported successfully at front-end until re indexing.

It's possible to display product at front-side without re indexing in Magento2?

[image]

Comment: This looks like serious issue but not getting any proper answer.

Comment: @Prits currently magento will start from first points. so will reindex all the 50lakh+50 product.

But in market extension are available which can fulfill your requirement.Below extension I have just checked.
https://mirasvit.com/magento-2-extensions/improved-asynchronous-reindex.html

Answer (score 0):

Magento should display the products in the frontend immediately after creating from the backend if you have set the values of:

- Category Products
- Product Categories
- Product Price
- Product EAV
- Stock
- Catalog Search

to **`Update On Save`**.

Please check and let me know if it helped.

You may need to reindex only first time after changing this setting.

**Update based on comment from @Prits:**
Magento keeps a change log in different change log tables (tables ending with **_cl**)

When Magento reindex runs, it checks for the entries in the change log table of respective index, and reindexes only those by default.

Comment: i have attached image please check it's already Update On Save mode

My product display front side with url:
Like:
www.example.com/testnewproduct.html


But it's not display in Newly added product due to foreach loop
which added in query more one table cataloginventory_stock_status
which only updated after reindexing
Let me know if i anything missing here

Comment: Have you done reindexing at least once?

Comment: Yes ,  I have done reindexing

Comment: @RutveeSojitra, which Magento version are you using?

Comment: Version : Magento 2.2.3

Comment: I have just tested in Magento 2.2.3 as well as in Magento 2.2.4. For me, in both installations it is working fine.

Comment: I have tested it with **`Flat Catalog`** setting **`On`** and **`Off`** both.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80223/discussion-between-rutvee-sojitra-and-mohit-kumar-arora).

Comment: Nice Explanation @MohitKumarArora will you please help me with this if i have 50 Lakh product and i have re-index all the data and it is working fine. But if new 50 products are added then is it required to re-index the data ? If yes then will you please tell me the re-indexing works from 1st product or just for the new 50 product which i have added ?

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2 reindex is required for these 8 indexers when any changes are made:

E.g.: when updating a product price the data should be reindexed to be correctly displayed on the frontend. The indexation sufficiently reduces time spent on calculating a final order price including cart price rules, bundle pricing, discounts, tier pricing, etc.

```
Category products;
Product categories;
Product price;
Product entity attribute value;
Stock;
Catalog rule product;
Catalog product rule;
Catalog search.
```

In older Magento versions indexation is dependent on the indexer.php file placed under the shell folder. In Magento 2 it’s managed by the bin/magento instead.

To reindex indexes in Magento 2 you can use several ways: reindex via a cron job and use manual reindex from the admin panel.

You can use Magento 2 manual reindex via the command line:

```
Log in to your Magento server admin panel as the file owner;
Use the next option:php bin\magento indexer:reindex where [indexer] is a space-separated list of indexers;
The option is suitable for reindexing all the store: php bin\magento indexer:reindex. In this case, you’ll see the corresponding results:
```

reindex-results-magento

However, reindexing of all indexers can take long, therefore, you’d better manage a cron job for the issue.

```
If you  want to see the list of all indexers, type in: php bin\magento indexer:info. Here you can find the name of a definite indexer, which is to be further reindexed through the command: php bin\magento indexer:reindex indexer_name (the name of a desired indexer is applied to the ‘_name’ part).
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Nice Explanation @Jack will you please help me with this if i have 50 Lakh product and i have re-index all the data and it is working fine. But if new 50 products are added then is it required to re-index the data ? If yes then will you please tell me the re-indexing works from 1st product or just for the new 50 product which i have added ?

Answer (score -2):

That is not possible because the re-index make Magento more organize with all the categories and the products.